# Design input of the 4 bit adder

Tags: digital-logic, adder

I have the answer. But i'm not sure how the input of the adder is derived.

Why is it a,b,1,1 for x and 0,a,b,0 for y?

Been searching multiple sources but i'm stuck. Trying to study for my exams.

[image: an]

[image]

Comment: `Why is it a,b,1,1 for x and 0,a,b,0 for y?` Perhaps they want to prevent an overflow. Seems rather arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X input is equal to \$ab \times 4 + 3\$. The Y input is equal to \$ab \times 2\$. Add them together and you get \$ab \times 6 + 3\$.

Comment: Hi there. I'm new in this, just wondering how u got ab x 4 + 3?

Comment: Shifting an integer value left by 2 bit positions is equivalent to multiplying by 4, so ab00 is equal to \$ab\times 4\$. Integer 3 is binary 0011, so ab11 is equal to \$ab\times 4 + 3\$.